# Adicionar imagem JsPDF

Tags: jspdf

Tenho este *script* que gera um **pdf** de uma `div`. Más as imagens que contem na `div` não são geradas no `pdf`, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$('#downloadpdf').click(function() 
                {
                    var doc = new jsPDF('landscape', 'pt', 'a4');
                        doc.addHTML($('#dowextrato'), function()
                    {
                        doc.save("relatorio-<?php echo $Pnome; ?>.pdf");
                    }); 
                });
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Falou você adicionar o parâmetro:

```
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160)
```

No site do plugin há um exemplo com imagens.

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Nessa demo há um exemplo com imagem em uma div.

https://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/RWMObL

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo!

Agora, sem querer abusar: "15,40,180,160" quais as posições?

Comment: Os parâmetros são: doc.addImage(imagem, 'formato da imagem', x, y, larguraimagem, alturaimagem);

Comment: Valeu amigo, obrigado mesmo!

Answer (score -1):

Para React:

Crie um `HTMLImageElement` e use-o como parâmetro da função `doc.addImage`

```js
import autoTable  from 'jspdf-autotable'
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'

const image = document.createElement('img')
image.setAttribute('src', '/assets/images/imagem.png')

const gerarPDF = () => {
  const doc = new jsPDF()
  autoTable(doc, {
    margin: {top: 40},  //"empurra" a tabela para baixo, deixando espaco para imagem
    head: cabecalho,
    body: dados,
    didDrawPage: data => {
      doc.addImage(image, 'PNG', data.settings.margin.left, 15, 60, 20)
    }
  })
  doc.save('nomeDoArquivo')
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Uso o Angular 11:

TS:

```html
    import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

   

     // PDF Print
async printPDF() {
  let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.html(this.geraEstruturaPDF(), {
  callback: (pdf) => {
     pdf.output("dataurlnewwindow");
  }
}) 


geraEstruturaPDF(){
        var style = "<style>";
        style = style + "@media print{tr{ page-break-after: auto; } }";
        style = style + "table{ width: 650px; font-family: helvetica; page-break- 
        inside:auto; float:none}";
        style = style + "table, tr, td, th { width: 650px; border-collapse: 
        collapse; page-break-inside:auto}";
        style = style + "thead { display:table-header-group }";
        style = style + "tbody {page-break-after: auto;}";
        style = style + "</style>";

        var html = "";
        html += '<body>';
        html += style;
        html += '<table style="margin: 20px;">';
        html += `<thead>
                <tr>
                  <td class="logo"><img src="./assets/logo.png" width="150" height="auto"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="titulo">Comprovante de transferência</td>
                </tr>`
    html += '</thead>';        
        html += '</table>';

 return html;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button (click)="printPDF()">Abrir página de impressão</button>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).